# Ошибка gradle в Android Studio - 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, gradle

Привет всем! Обновился с 2.3.3 версии AS, теперь вылезают эти ошибки(картинка).[image: Не понимаю, на что он ругается]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.android.start.listviewsample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

Информация о программе:
Android SDK tools version: 26.1.1
Android Platform Version: API 27 revision 1.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше проводить в виде текста

Comment: Как это? Я просто ньюфаг(

Comment: Попробуйте нажать на кнопку "disable offline mode". И бета версии использовать - рискованное занятие как по мне.

Comment: Я обновил sdk, переместил gradle в директорию локального диска и поменял код грейдла(обновил сверяя с разных ресурсов). В общем, проблема решена!